# Hibernate join without loding the join entity by default

Tags: java, database, hibernate, criteria

I want to use a join without loding the join entity by default.

```
@Entity 
public class Author { 
  @Id 
  private Long id; 
  private String name; 
  private String genre; 
  private int age; 
   
  @OneToMany 
  private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(); 
  ...
}


@Entity 
public class Book { 
  @Id private Long id; 
  private String title; 
  private String isbn; 

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
  @JoinColumn(name = "author_id") 
  private Author author; 
  ... 
}
```

If I load the authors with criteria api via

```
criteriaQuery.select(rootAuthor)
```

all books to all authors were loaded.

How can I prevent loading the joined entities by default and only load them when addressing the entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `FetchType.LAZY` to the books object in the Author class to lazy load books.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: `@OneToMany` is lazy by default, I bet TC is observing "loading" using IDE debugger.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately this also does not work.